# Mocha: how do I use the assert.reject in typescript with promise in params?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, es6-promise, chai

how do I use the assert.reject in typescript with promise in params?

here is my code:

```
import { assert } from "chai";
import { suite, test, timeout, slow } from "mocha-typescript";
import "mocha";
import { car } from "./Car"; // module that run your function

let carVIN: string = "1234567890"; // this car has four wheel;

@suit
export class CarTest() {
  @test
  public async oneWheelsCar() {
      const wheels = await car.findWheelsByCarId(carVIN);
      assert.isRejected(wheels, "Expected to have four wheels");
  }

}
```

My question is how do I make my carId function to run like promise because my problem is assert.isRejected run early before the carId error return back.

I tried this below:

```
assert.throws(carId, Error, "Expected to be error ");
```

and I also try to use try-catch to wrap my function:

```
import { assert } from "chai";
import { suite, test, timeout, slow } from "mocha-typescript";
import "mocha";
import { car } from "./Car"; // module that run your function

let carVIN: string = "1234567890"; // this car has four wheel;

@suit
export class CarTest() {
  @test
  public async oneWheelsCar() {
      try {
        const wheels = await car.findWheelsByCarId(carVIN);
        assert.isNotString(wheels, "Expected to be error but return four wheels");
      } catch (error) {
        assert.throws(error, Error, "Expected to be error ");
      }

    }

}
```

I had tried to use chai-as-promise, but the example is not that clear in the their github repo.

Visit https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised#readme

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `await`. `await` resolves promise to actual value or throws exception (simplified view).

So, after this line:

```
const wheels = await car.findWheelsByCarId(carVIN);
```

`wheels` is not a promise, but actual `wheel` (or whatever).

Change it to:

```
const wheelsPromise = car.findWheelsByCarId(carVIN); // no await
```

And then this:

```
assert.isRejected(wheelsPromise, "Expected to have four wheels");
```

Should work as expected.

Comment: My point is to used chai-as-promise so I can wait for the wheels to come back. I can't change wheels => wheelsPromise to think it is work. that does not work for my case.